# using regular expression to retrieve the BSSID of the networks

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i run the following command in to retrieved the list of BSSIDs:

```
netsh wlan show networks mode=Bssid | findstr "SSID"
```

and i got this:

```
SSID 1 : John
    BSSID 1                 : b0:e7:54:f2:97:f9
SSID 2 : 2WIRE519
    BSSID 1                 : 00:1e:c7:fb:f5:89
SSID 3 : Home SCW
    BSSID 1                 : 00:1e:c7:fb:40:11
SSID 4 : CBV704W-AFE5
    BSSID 1                 : 00:1a:2b:57:2e:75
SSID 5 : neboi
    BSSID 1                 : 34:ef:44:76:e2:90
```

And now i want to store the individual BSSID by using regular expression and i
try this:

```
"^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]$
```

...but is not working. Can anyone help me with this?  Here's some sample code:

```
string sPattern = "^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9]$";
            if (Regex.IsMatch(result, sPattern))
                Console.WriteLine("Pattern Found");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Pattern Not Found");
```

Comment: You appear to misunderstand the meaning of the `^` and `$` anchors. Without them, I believe your regex should match, although it's not very elegant or precise.

Comment: indeed it works since "Pattern Found" is display.

Comment: Just a note: You're actually looking for a way to parse mac addresses

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}[:-]){5}(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{2})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static Regex MyRegex = new Regex(
      "([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}",
    RegexOptions.Compiled);

static bool isBSSID(string line)
{
    return MyRegex.IsMatch(line);
}

void Main()
{
string lines = 
"SSID 1 : John\n"+
    "BSSID 1                 : b0:e7:54:f2:97:f9\n"+
"SSID 2 : 2WIRE519\n"+
    "BSSID 1                 : 00:1e:c7:fb:f5:89\n"+
"SSID 3 : Home SCW\n"+
    "BSSID 1                 : 00:1e:c7:fb:40:11\n"+
"SSID 4 : CBV704W-AFE5\n"+
    "BSSID 1                 : 00:1a:2b:57:2e:75\n"+
"SSID 5 : neboi\n"+
    "BSSID 1                 : 34:ef:44:76:e2:90";

    Console.WriteLine(isBSSID(lines)+"\n-----");    
    foreach (string line in lines.Split('\n'))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(isBSSID(line));       
    }
    //result: 
        //True
        //-----
        //False
        //True
        //False
        //True
        //False
        //True
        //False
        //True
        //False
        //True
}
```